# How to add multiple points in LineString from JSON to GeoJSON with python?

Tags: python, json, formatting, geojson

I have this JSON with coordinates for a Line Feature. I'm struggling trying to get this JSON into a GeoJSON format so I can plot it. Json and Python code below. I'm trying to format this with Python 3x. I think I'm almost there just struggling with the for loop in the line section. I got it to work with with just the first set of coordinates. Thanks !

```js
[{
    "type": "linestring",
    "points": [{
        "lat": 37.918647943,
        "lon": 23.761094017
    }, {
        "lat": 37.764186425,
        "lon": 24.043867088
    }, {
        "lat": 37.762555035,
        "lon": 24.045284834
    }, {
        "lat": 37.759292113,
        "lon": 24.048120252
    }, {
        "lat": 37.757909899,
        "lon": 24.050360246
    }, {
        "lat": 37.754357436,
        "lon": 24.056116962
    }, {
        "lat": 37.752949276,
        "lon": 24.058567669
    }, {
        "lat": 37.751417202,
        "lon": 24.061233635
    }, {
        "lat": 37.74953827,
        "lon": 24.064503082
    }, {
        "lat": 37.748200181,
        "lon": 24.065451555
    }, {
        "lat": 37.747314483,
        "lon": 24.065389252
    }],
    "entity_id": "77101",
    "popup": "\u003Ch5\u003E\u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u039b\u03b1\u03c5\u03c1\u03af\u03bf\u03c5 - \u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u0391\u03c1\u03b3\u03c5\u03c1\u03bf\u03cd\u03c0\u03bf\u03bb\u03b7\u03c2\u003C\/h5\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E400 kV\u003C\/div\u003E\n",
    "path": "{\u0022color\u0022:\u0022#3388ff\u0022,\u0022opacity\u0022:\u00221.0\u0022,\u0022stroke\u0022:true,\u0022weight\u0022:3,\u0022className\u0022:\u0022id_77101 red\u0022,\u0022fill\u0022:\u0022depends\u0022,\u0022fillColor\u0022:\u0022*\u0022,\u0022fillOpacity\u0022:\u00220.0\u0022}"
}, {
    "type": "linestring",
    "points": [{
        "lat": 38.524903863,
        "lon": 23.167894542
    }, {
        "lat": 38.524705211,
        "lon": 23.167839471
    }, {
        "lat": 38.137414714,
        "lon": 23.828298758
    }, {
        "lat": 38.134480753,
        "lon": 23.830543492
    }, {
        "lat": 38.134170241,
        "lon": 23.832346632
    }, {
        "lat": 38.133976038,
        "lon": 23.834457466
    }, {
        "lat": 38.134049661,
        "lon": 23.835541307
    }, {
        "lat": 38.133833198,
        "lon": 23.835427687
    }],
    "entity_id": "77102",
    "popup": "\u003Ch5\u003E\u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u0391\u03b3.\u03a3\u03c4\u03b5\u03c6\u03ac\u03bd\u03bf\u03c5 - \u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u039b\u03ac\u03c1\u03c5\u03bc\u03bd\u03b1\u03c2\u003C\/h5\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022pop-up-label\u0022\u003EDescription:\u003C\/div\u003E 2B\u0026#039;B\u0026#039;\/400\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E400 kV\u003C\/div\u003E\n",
    "path": "{\u0022color\u0022:\u0022#3388ff\u0022,\u0022opacity\u0022:\u00221.0\u0022,\u0022stroke\u0022:true,\u0022weight\u0022:3,\u0022className\u0022:\u0022id_77102 red\u0022,\u0022fill\u0022:\u0022depends\u0022,\u0022fillColor\u0022:\u0022*\u0022,\u0022fillOpacity\u0022:\u00220.0\u0022}"
}, {
    "type": "linestring",
    "points": [{
        "lat": 41.393877564,
        "lon": 23.311903052
    }, {
        "lat": 41.391621317,
        "lon": 23.314187524
    }, {
        "lat": 41.389758983,
        "lon": 23.316073
    },  {
        "lat": 40.699766659,
        "lon": 22.916499355
    }, {
        "lat": 40.698006009,
        "lon": 22.918954289
    }, {
        "lat": 40.695974697,
        "lon": 22.920407418
    }, {
        "lat": 40.693381223,
        "lon": 22.922437615
    }, {
        "lat": 40.692491512,
        "lon": 22.922664982
    }],
    "entity_id": "77103",
    "popup": "\u003Ch5\u003E\u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u0398\u03b5\u03c3\/\u03bd\u03af\u03ba\u03b7\u03c2 - \u0392\u03bf\u03c5\u03bb\u03b3\u03b1\u03c1\u03af\u03b1\u003C\/h5\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022pop-up-label\u0022\u003EDescription:\u003C\/div\u003E B\u0026#039;B\u0026#039;\/400\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E400 kV\u003C\/div\u003E\n",
    "path": "{\u0022color\u0022:\u0022#3388ff\u0022,\u0022opacity\u0022:\u00221.0\u0022,\u0022stroke\u0022:true,\u0022weight\u0022:3,\u0022className\u0022:\u0022id_77103 red\u0022,\u0022fill\u0022:\u0022depends\u0022,\u0022fillColor\u0022:\u0022*\u0022,\u0022fillOpacity\u0022:\u00220.0\u0022}"
}, {
    "type": "linestring",
    "points": [{
        "lat": 40.692461619,
        "lon": 22.922357749
    }, {
        "lat": 40.755326724,
        "lon": 22.850940857
    }, {
        "lat": 40.758623291,
        "lon": 22.848183012
    }, {
        "lat": 41.065846201,
        "lon": 22.658634921
    }, {
        "lat": 41.067743292,
        "lon": 22.655239987
    },  {

        "lat": 41.112288315,
        "lon": 22.575224675
    }, {
        "lat": 41.113750897,
        "lon": 22.572584693
    }, {
        "lat": 41.116059427,
        "lon": 22.568437392
    }, {
        "lat": 41.12034928,
        "lon": 22.564997041
    }, {
        "lat": 41.125058394,
        "lon": 22.561237357
    }, {
        "lat": 41.129138167,
        "lon": 22.561183964
    }],
    "entity_id": "77104",
    "popup": "\u003Ch5\u003E\u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u0398\u03b5\u03c3\/\u03bd\u03af\u03ba\u03b7\u03c2 - FYROM\u003C\/h5\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022pop-up-label\u0022\u003EDescription:\u003C\/div\u003E B\u0026#039;B\u0026#039;\/400\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E400 kV\u003C\/div\u003E\n",
    "path": "{\u0022color\u0022:\u0022#3388ff\u0022,\u0022opacity\u0022:\u00221.0\u0022,\u0022stroke\u0022:true,\u0022weight\u0022:3,\u0022className\u0022:\u0022id_77104 red\u0022,\u0022fill\u0022:\u0022depends\u0022,\u0022fillColor\u0022:\u0022*\u0022,\u0022fillOpacity\u0022:\u00220.0\u0022}"
}, {
    "type": "linestring",
    "points": [{
        "lat": 40.7901584769,
        "lon": 23.0480705193
    }, {
        "lat": 40.7903523946,
        "lon": 23.0492358221
    }, {
        "lat": 40.7901050443,
        "lon": 23.0527869346
    },   {
        "lat": 41.043691983,
        "lon": 24.249864576
    }, {
        "lat": 41.045358111,
        "lon": 24.25415432
    }, {
        "lat": 41.04630753,
        "lon": 24.256609089
    }, {
        "lat": 41.046164193,
        "lon": 24.2602733
    }],
    "entity_id": "77105",
    "popup": "\u003Ch5\u003E\u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u039b\u03b1\u03b3\u03ba\u03b1\u03b4\u03ac - \u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u03a6\u03b9\u03bb\u03af\u03c0\u03c0\u03c9\u03bd\u003C\/h5\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022pop-up-label\u0022\u003EDescription:\u003C\/div\u003E B\u0026#039;B\u0026#039;B\u0026#039;\/400\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E400 kV\u003C\/div\u003E\n",
    "path": "{\u0022color\u0022:\u0022#3388ff\u0022,\u0022opacity\u0022:\u00221.0\u0022,\u0022stroke\u0022:true,\u0022weight\u0022:3,\u0022className\u0022:\u0022id_77105 red\u0022,\u0022fill\u0022:\u0022depends\u0022,\u0022fillColor\u0022:\u0022*\u0022,\u0022fillOpacity\u0022:\u00220.0\u0022}"
}, {
    "type": "linestring",
    "points": [{
        "lat": 40.78983174,
        "lon": 23.04660084
    }, {
        "lat": 40.78958078,
        "lon": 23.04564668
    }, {
        "lat": 40.78955252,
        "lon": 23.04247145
    }, {
        "lat": 40.79761609,
        "lon": 23.02745817
    }, {
        "lat": 40.79868402,
        "lon": 22.96633164
    },  {
        "lat": 40.62123973221768,
        "lon": 21.72502141299155
    }, {
        "lat": 40.619958771459004,
        "lon": 21.721002325337444
    }, {
        "lat": 40.61876412645359,
        "lon": 21.71725480736431
    }, {
        "lat": 40.61763871618877,
        "lon": 21.71372480244598
    }, {
        "lat": 40.616253421804615,
        "lon": 21.709380286795067
    }, {
        "lat": 40.6148332836148,
        "lon": 21.704927337949705
    }, {
        "lat": 40.61390429997776,
        "lon": 21.70201462068876
    }, {
        "lat": 40.61517977186133,
        "lon": 21.698154785687546
    }, {
        "lat": 40.616549620077215,
        "lon": 21.693351729497877
    }, {
        "lat": 40.61769071025425,
        "lon": 21.689027178782595
    }, {
        "lat": 40.61787118798994,
        "lon": 21.688146238927636
    }, {
        "lat": 40.617999818469684,
        "lon": 21.688271824830505
    }],
    "entity_id": "77106",
    "popup": "\u003Ch5\u003E\u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u0391\u03bc\u03c5\u03bd\u03c4\u03b1\u03af\u03bf\u03c5 - \u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u039b\u03b1\u03b3\u03ba\u03b1\u03b4\u03ac\u003C\/h5\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022pop-up-label\u0022\u003EDescription:\u003C\/div\u003E 2B\u0026#039;B\u0026#039;\/400\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E400 kV\u003C\/div\u003E\n",
    "path": "{\u0022color\u0022:\u0022#3388ff\u0022,\u0022opacity\u0022:\u00221.0\u0022,\u0022stroke\u0022:true,\u0022weight\u0022:3,\u0022className\u0022:\u0022id_77106 red\u0022,\u0022fill\u0022:\u0022depends\u0022,\u0022fillColor\u0022:\u0022*\u0022,\u0022fillOpacity\u0022:\u00220.0\u0022}"
}, {
    "type": "linestring",
    "points": [{
        "lat": 40.692458304,
        "lon": 22.922002748
    }, {
        "lat": 40.69332022,
        "lon": 22.921692973
    }, {
        "lat": 40.696125972,
        "lon": 22.919245068
    },  {
        "lat": 40.797415962,
        "lon": 23.020151234
    }, {
        "lat": 40.797360122,
        "lon": 23.023127364
    }, {
        "lat": 40.79730334,
        "lon": 23.02732208
    }, {
        "lat": 40.7892307,
        "lon": 23.04235039
    }, {
        "lat": 40.78915542,
        "lon": 23.04584343
    }, {
        "lat": 40.78940636,
        "lon": 23.04679502
    }],
    "entity_id": "77107",
    "popup": "\u003Ch5\u003E\u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u0398\u03b5\u03c3\/\u03bd\u03af\u03ba\u03b7\u03c2 - \u039a\u03a5\u03a4 \u039b\u03b1\u03b3\u03ba\u03b1\u03b4\u03ac\u003C\/h5\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022pop-up-label\u0022\u003EDescription:\u003C\/div\u003E 2B\u0026#039;B\u0026#039;\/400\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv\u003E400 kV\u003C\/div\u003E\n",
    "path": "{\u0022color\u0022:\u0022#3388ff\u0022,\u0022opacity\u0022:\u00221.0\u0022,\u0022stroke\u0022:true,\u0022weight\u0022:3,\u0022className\u0022:\u0022id_77107 red\u0022,\u0022fill\u0022:\u0022depends\u0022,\u0022fillColor\u0022:\u0022*\u0022,\u0022fillOpacity\u0022:\u00220.0\u0022}"
}]
```

Python code below

```
    from sys import argv
from os.path import exists
import simplejson as json 

out_file = r"C:\Users\xxxxxx.json"
in_file = r"C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\xxx.json"

data = json.load(open(in_file))


geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [i['lat'], i['lon']]#This line here is not correct. This is where I am struggling.
            },
        "properties" : d,
     } for d in data 
        for i in d['points']#This line here is not correct. This is where I am struggling. 
    ]
}


output = open(out_file, 'w')
json.dump(geojson, output)

print (geojson)
```

Comment: Note GeoJSON line geometry has coords for each point in lon,lat order not lat, lon. See [spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#page-22).

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is just a data structure. Can't embed code inside the JSON. You need to append points to a list for each line and append each feature to a features list that makes up the GeoJSON.

```python
import json

out_file = r"C:\Users\xxxxxx.json"
in_file = r"C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\xxx.json"

with open(in_file) as fin:
    data = json.load(fin)

features = []
for d in data:
    coords = []
    for pt in d['points']:
        coords.append((pt["lon"], pt["lat"]))
    features.append({
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": coords
        },
        "properties": {
            "entity_id" : d["entity_id"]           
          }
    })

with open(out_file, 'w') as output:
    geojson = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": features
    }
    json.dump(geojson, output)

print(geojson)
```